# create Calendar at a time error

Tags: android, calendar

i try to create Calendar like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25);
    calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 22);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 22);
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 2);
```

this time is near with current but my log wrong:
Log.i("naq", ""+(calendar.getTimeInMillis()-System.currentTimeMillis()));
i want (calendar.getTimeInMillis()-System.currentTimeMillis()) =0 (or nearly )

Comment: have you checked the timezone the calendar uses ?

Comment: i want (calendar.getTimeInMillis()-System.currentTimeMillis()) =0 (or )
how can i set timezone?

Comment: it can't be quite 0, as you don't specify the millis. As for the timezone, there are various methods, the documentation is quite clearer than I could be in a simple comment.

Comment: when i use Calendar.getInstance(); timezone is like timezone of system

Comment: could you, for instance, post the current output of your code?

Comment: calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 10); fix:
 calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 9); done

Comment: Although both work, you should use `Calendar.OCTOBER` instead of 9; it is much easier to understand. The reason 10 was wrong is because it January is 0, February is 1, etc. You can see all the constant values here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#JANUARY